# mapping associative array with another associative array

Tags: php

I found a way to solve my problem, but I want to see if there is any better or clear solution for this. I have two associative arrays like this:

```
$person= [
    "A" => [
            "sur" => "a",
            "fir" => "andras"
            ],
    "C" =>  [
            "sur" => "b",
            "fir" => "balint"
            ]
];
$data = [
    "A" => ["011", "012", "013"],
    "C" => ["021", "022"]
];
```

I want to map the two arrays if their keys are equal. So the result should look like this:

```
$person= [
    "A" => [
            "sur" => "a",
            "fir" => "andras",
            "tel" => ["011", "012", "013"]
            ],
    "C" =>  [
            "sur" => "b",
            "fir" => "balint",
            "tel" => ["021", "022"]
            ]
];
```

My code:

```
foreach ( array_intersect_key(array_keys($data,$person)) as $id) {
    $person[$id]['tel'] = $data[$id];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please declare your [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33912361/1157100)

Comment: What is not clear about the sample data (on both SE sites) is that we don't know what the desired result should be when one array has a key that the other array doesn't have.  Is person the master array or data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to save some lines of code and to use the appropriate functions that PHP provides then yes, this is a perfect solution.

On the other point of view on somebody who wants to quickly read through your code and know whats happening, then I would have suggested a nested loop.

For both cases, a comment above your loop would be very appreciated.